# Iteration not working in 'with open' of CSV module in Python

Tags: python, csv

I want to create 2 or more CSV files using `for` but only 1 CSV is created.

```
import csv
import os

foods = ['pasta','chocolate']
for food in foods:
    with open(food+'.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['id', 'Category', 'Name']

        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        os.chdir('E:/data/'+food)
        folders = os.listdir(os.curdir)
        for filename in folders:
                writer.writerow({'id':'', 'Category':food, 'Name':filename})
```

In this case, only `pasta.csv` is successfully created. I want the `chocolate.csv` also created.
Any solutions? Thanks

Comment: I would suspect that the `chocolate.csv` file has been created in the `E:/data` folder because of the `chdir` in first iteration.

Comment: So what's wrong with the `chdir`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the for is working and the problem is in the `os.chdir`. You only need it to get the list of directories, you should consider using `glob` instead:

```
import csv
from glob import glob

foods = ['pasta','chocolate']
for food in foods:
    with open(food+'.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['id', 'Category', 'Name']

        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        folders = glob('E:/data/'+food+'/*/')
        for filename in folders:
                writer.writerow({'id':'', 'Category':food, 'Name':filename})
```

Comment: Thanks @AC_ , now both are created, however the content of the CSV is not the filenames inside the chocolate and pasta folders

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add the wildcard in the argument of `glob`. It should work now.